# Understanding A Chain of Imports in Python

Tags: python, import, python-3.x

I know there are several similar questions, but I'm struggling to understand the error I'm getting and browsing the docs and similar questions hasn't helped yet.  If anything, the similar questions make me feel like what I'm doing is right.

I have the following files:

***src/main.py***

```
from pack import pack

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pack.exec("Hello Universe!")
```

***src/pack/pack.py***

```
import util

def exec(text):
    util.write(text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    exec("Hello World!")
```

***src/pack/util.py***

```
def write(text):
    print(text)
```

***src/pack/_*init*_.py***

```
EMPTY FILE
```

---

When I run `python pack.py` from the `src/pack` directory, it works (prints "Hello World!").  However when I run `python main.py` from the `src` directory I get the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../src/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pack import pack
  File ".../src/pack/pack.py", line 1, in <module>
    import util
ImportError: No module named util
```

---

If I change the import line in `pack.py` to `from . import util` as suggested, effectively the opposite occours.  `main.py` runs successfully, however now `pack.py` fails, raising:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../src/pack/pack.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import util
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

---

I would have thought that imports are relative to the current location, and as such you ought to be able to construct a chain of imports like this.  It seems very odd to me that module is supposed to import a sibling file differently depending on where the program starts.

Can someone explain why this error occurs in one way but not the other, and if there is some way to allow this file structure to run whether I want to run from `main.py` or `pack.py`?

Comment: If you want to work with proper modules without the headache of creating them manually, I suggest using https://nbdev.fast.ai/  It has some learning curve, but on the long run is saves you a ton of time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will have trouble making the import work in both cases. This is because in one case you are running pack.py as the main file and in another you run it as part of a package.

When you run it as a standalone script `python pack.py`, the "pack" directory gets added to the PYTHONPATH, meaning that you can import any module in it. Hence, `import util` will work.

When you run `python main.py` you add the src directory to your PYTHONPATH. This means that any module or package in `src`, for example the `pack` directory, now becomes importable. Hence `from pack import pack`. However, to access `util.py` you now need to do `from pack import util`. You can also do `from . import util` from within `pack.py`, as you noticed.

But you can't really do both at the same time. Either `src/` is the main directory or `src/pack` is.

The obvious, but wrong solution, is to let the main.py add the `src/pack` directory to the PYTHONPATH. That will work, but it's not a good idea. The correct way to do this is to make up your mind. Is `src/pack` a module that should be imported via `import pack` or is it just a folder with a bunch of Python scripts? Decide! :-)

I think in this case its' obvious that `src/pack` should be a module. So then treat it like a module, and make sure it's available like a module. Then you can `from pack import util` even when running `pack.py` as a main script.

How do you do that? Well, basically you either install the pack module in your site-packages, or you add the `src` directory to the PYTHONPATH. That last one is what you want during development. You can either do it manually with `export PYTHONPATH=<path>` or you can let your testrunners do it for you. You don't have a testrunner? Well you should, but that's another question. :)

For installing it permanently once you don't do development anymore, take a look at [Distribute](http://packages.python.org/distribute/). It includes a testrunner. ;)

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "`src/pack` should be a module"?  Do you mean the directory itself should be a module?

Comment: @dimo414: I mean it should have a `__init__.py`. That makes it behave like a module. Strictly speaking the python terminology for a directory that is a module is "package" but that tends to confuse people, including me. :)

Comment: @LennartRegebro: the terminology is indeed confusing. As a newbie trying to find a good mental model, my current is: ***"Package is a module that can contain submodules"***. But they are modules nevertheless: you can import them alone `import pack` and use their objects (in `__init__.py`) and submodules. `__init__.py` makes a directory be seen as a package.

Answer (score 4):

Your link is to python 2.7 documentation, but it looks like you are using Python 3.x.

See here: http://docs.python.org/py3k/ for the correct docs.

Python 3 removes implicit relative import. That is, you cannot import packages within the same module in the same way anymore.

You  need to use `from . import util`, this is an explicitly relative import and is allowed. `import X` no longer checks the current directory. Instead it only check the entries in sys.path. This includes the directory of the script was started and python's standard library.

Comment: Ok, thanks for explaining that to me.  Trouble is, now it doesn't work /the other/ way.  Running `main.py` works, but `pack.py` does not.

Comment: @dimo414: That's because you're supposed to use `-m` to run `pack.pack`.

Comment: @dimo414, running scripts inside of packages is frowned upon. Any script you want to run shouldn't be inside of a package.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing __init__.py in your pack directory.

Create an empty file called __init__.py in your pack directory.

Comment: +1 - the `__init__.py` file will tell python that the directory is a package. You can specify what you want to be loaded or not and other things in the `__init__.py` file but an empty file is suficient and will work.

Comment: Forgive me for not mentioning it, but there is an empty `__init__.py` file.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in the [correct documentation](http://docs.python.org/py3k/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references) supports your theory that this form of importing should work.

Comment: Ok thanks, fixed the link.  As best I can tell however, the code I have should still run.

Comment: I did, it isn't very clear on the subject imho.  The purpose of my question is that running a file in / out of a package seems to me to be counterintuitive, I'm trying to understand the best practice in this regard, and if there is any way to solve my specific problem, being able to run in and out of the package.

Comment: The correct way to run a package is to pass `-m` to the executable.