# python conflicts in two external packages

Tags: python, package, conflict

I am writing code to combine functions from the python rawdog RSS reader library and the BeautifulSoup webscraping library.  There is a conflict somewhere in the innards that I am trying to overcome.

I can replicate the problem with this simplified code:

```
    import sys, gzip
    def scrape(filename):
        contents = gzip.open(filename,'rb').read()
        contents = contents.decode('utf-8','replace')
        import BeautifulSoup as BS
        print 'before rawdog: ', len(BS.BeautifulSoup(contents)) # prints 4, correct answer
        from rawdoglib import rawdog as rd
        print 'after rawdog: ', len(BS.BeautifulSoup(contents)) # prints 3, incorrect answer
```

It does not matter what order or where I do the imports, the import of rawdog always causes the BS.BeautifulSoup() method to return the wrong response.  I don't actually need rawdog anymore by the time I get to needing BeautifulSoup, so I've tried removing the package at that point, but BS is still broken.  Fixes I have tried that have not worked:

- I noticed that the rawdog code does its own import of BeautifulSoup.  So I tried removing `import BeautifulSoup` from the rawdog code and re-installing rawdog
- removing the rawdog modules before importing BeautifulSoup:

  - `for x in filter(lambda y: y.startswith('rawdog'), sys.modules.keys()): del sys.modules[x]`
- importing more specific classes/methods from rawdog, e.g `from rawdoglib.rawdog import FeedState`
- give the problem method a new name, before and after importing rawdog: `from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as BS`
- `from __future__ import absolute_import`

No luck, I always get len(BeautifulSoup(contents)) == 3 if rawdog was ever imported into the namespace.  Both packages are complex enough that I haven't been able to figure out exactly what the problem overlap is, and I'm not sure what tools to use to try to figure that out, other than searching through dir(BeautifulSoup) and dir(rawdog), where I haven't found good clues.

Updates, responding to answers:
I omitted that the problem does not occur with every input file, which is crucial, sorry.  The offending files are quite large so I don't think I can post them here.  I will try to figure out the crucial difference between the good and bad files and post it.  Thanks for the debugging help so far.

Further debugging! I have identified this block in the input text as problematic:

```
    function SwitchMenu(obj){
      if(document.getElementById){
      var el = document.getElementById(obj);
      var ar = document.getElementById("masterdiv").getElementsByTagName("span"); //DynamicDrive.com change
         if(el.style.display != "block"){ //DynamicDrive.com change
         for (var i=0; i<ar.length; i++){
            if (ar[i].className=="submenu") //DynamicDrive.com change
            ar[i].style.display = "none";
      }
      el.style.display = "block";
      }else{
        el.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

}

If I comment out this block, then I get the correct parse through BeautifulSoup with or without the rawdog import.  With the block, rawdog + BeautifulSoup is faulty.  So should I just search my input for a block like this, or is there a better workaround?

Comment: This looks very weird (to me) although I've never used either library.  I wonder if `rawdoglib` monkey patches `BeautifulSoup`.  I would try grepping the source for `rawdoglib` looking for imports of `BeautifulSoup` and see if they do anything weird in those modules.

Comment: Can you post the offending file? Because if I process a file with content `<a><b><c>c</c></b></a>`, I get the correct result and `rawdoglib` import does not change a thing.

Comment: I've looked through the rawdog source and it only appears to import BeautifulSoup in one place. Removing that doesn't fix things? You should post a minimal example that includes data. Not importing it from a gzip-compressed external file decoded from UTF-8, unless that turns out to be an integral part of the problem.

Comment: "So should I just search my input for a block like this, or is there a better workaround?" But you don't know what it is about this chunk that triggers the problem. So who knows what other chunks would also trigger it? Now that you have the offending block, can you embed it in a _short_ file and create a stand-alone demonstration? It's hard to unravel this without being able to reproduce the problem...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a bug in `rawdoglib.feedparser.py`. `rawdog` is monkey patching `smglib`:
on line 198 it reads:

```
if sgmllib.endbracket.search(' <').start(0):
    class EndBracketMatch:
        endbracket = re.compile('''([^'"<>]|"[^"]*"(?=>|/|\s|\w+=)|'[^']*'(?=>|/|\s|\w+=))*(?=[<>])|.*?(?=[<>])''')
        def search(self,string,index=0):
            self.match = self.endbracket.match(string,index)
            if self.match: return self
        def start(self,n):
            return self.match.end(n)
    sgmllib.endbracket = EndBracketMatch()
```

This is a script to reproduce the error:

```
contents = '''<a><ar "none";                                                 
</a> '''                                                                     
import BeautifulSoup as BS                                                   
print 'before rawdog: ', len(BS.BeautifulSoup(contents)) # prints 4, correct answer
from rawdoglib import rawdog as rd                                           
print 'after rawdog: ', len(BS.BeautifulSoup(contents)) # prints 3, incorrect
```

It breaks on the "<" inside the "a" tag. In the OP's snippet, it is triggered by the line: `for (var i=0; i<ar.length; i++){` (note the "<" char).

Issue submitted on rawdog's ML: http://lists.us-lot.org/pipermail/rawdog-users/2012-August/000327.html

Comment: Nice find. Some lessons learned: (1) [monkey patching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch) is almost always a bad idea; (2) package A might conflict with directly imported package B not directly, but by messing with package C that they both import.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue you're having is a chain of `imports`; that the two different places you're importing the `BS` package are conflicting.

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226893/understanding-a-chain-of-imports-in-python) might be what you need, then.

(Also, `BS` package is a wonderful thing to be able to say in a serious context.)

Comment: Since the problem persists when `import BeautifulSoup` is removed from the rawdog source, this can't be it (unless there was misreporting).

Comment: I was more implying that he should try removing the BeautifulSoup import in the main file, which I didn't understand him to have done. IIRC Python will let you recursively access imports, so it would run off of the BeautifulSoup import in rawdog.

Comment: `import os; print sys.path` doesnt work even though `os` imports `sys`.

Comment: I did try to omit the separate import of BeautifulSoup, calling it through rawdog this way: `from rawdoglib import rawdog; BS= sys.modules['BeautifulSoup']; print len(BS.BeautifulSoup(contents))`, this gave me the answer '3' as before.  Even though rawdog does not explicitly patch BeautifulSoup that I can tell, there is some weird interaction.

Comment: @chown which version of Python are you using? Apparently this feature was set as not default in 3.x.

Comment: How about using `from rawdog import BeautifuSoup` instead of importing both? That seems to work with my 2.7.3 client.

Comment: @rsegal Python 2.7.3.  I'm not sure of how Python 3.x deals with this situation though so you could very well be correct.

Answer (score 0):

If rawdog can trigger the bug without importing `BeautifulSoup` (I take it you've checked that it's not imported indirectly?), they must have a shared dependency that is somehow loaded inconsistently. But the problem need not be monkey-patching: If they load different versions of the same library, you can get inconsistent behavior. E.g., if one of them uses a special import path, provides its own version of a top-level module, or has code like this:

```
try: 
    import ElementPath 
except ImportError: 
    ElementPath = _SimpleElementPath()
```

To see if this is the problem, try the following: Load `BeautifulSoup` by itself, nothing else, and dump the list of modules and their location:

```
import BeautifulSoup
import sys
sys.stdout = open("soup-modules.txt", "w")
for k,v in sorted(sys.modules.items()):
    if v:
        print k, v.__dict__.get('__file__')
```

Then do the same with rawdog and diff the outputs. If you see a module with the same name but a different origin, that's probably your culprit.

Comment: The "shared dependency" is `sgmllib` and it's badly monkey-patched by `rawdog`. See my reply: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11937081/python-conflicts-in-two-external-packages/11950085#11950085

Comment: Ha, well done! I could have saved myself the trouble if only I'd read this question a few minutes later than I did...